# Difficulties with using LM358 Op-amp

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, opto-isolator

Basically (Although I'm using an LM358 op amp):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Fp35k5X.png]

Is what I'm trying to design, if I change the current source from the 48uA to 8uA the output on the simulation changes but the output does not in physical testing which leads me to believe that something on the op-amp is incorrect in terms of hookups or what not.

This is how I am currently hooking up the op-amp in terms of the pin diagram of the LM358:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/w8wDP8k.jpg]

What I did notice is that when I do not have the +V connection hooked up to 5V there is a small change whenever I vary the current but that seems to me that the current is entirely bypassing the op-amp entirely since when I short the inverting input and the output (Removing the 100K resistor) the difference is greater. When I do connect the +5V to +V then the volt meter jumps up to ~4V and just stays there, varying the current does not change anything so I'm completely stumped on why it seems to ignore the op amp without +V and only wants to take +V voltage and ignore everything else when it is connected.

When either the 5V bias from the non-inverting lead or the +V pin is set to ground the op amp seems to not function and any current I deliver just goes straight through the resistor to the volt meter, changing the current does change the voltage but it's just a V = IR relation and nothing to do with the op amp.

When the +V and the non-inverting lead have voltage bias then it decides to just hit some voltage value and stay there and no changing the current seems to do anything. So it seems like the 5V is just hitting the volt meter and drowning out anything else.

Any ideas on what I may be missing?

**Edit:**

So I've went ahead and provided 3.3V to the input and 5V to the rail so there is that 1.5V difference between them.

So I've done the following to test it:
1.
Changed the 100k resistor that connects the inverting input and output to 10k because I thought that it was providing a voltage that was too close to the 5V supply and that might be causing problems and didn't change.

2.
Removed the resistor entirely so there is nothing connecting the inverting input to the output and the same thing, nothing changed.

3.
Looked at my circuit again but I don't see any shorts or anything that could be allowing a bypass so I'm stumped.

Just so weird, if I don't have any voltage to the +V pin it bypasses the op amp entirely and I can measure the change in the current in the volt meter through resistances which makes sense because obviously the op amp isn't turned on.
But when I do provide the +V pin power and try to keep the inputs 1.5V away from the rail it just seems to only output 1 single voltage value and ignores the current source from the inverting pin.

Answer (score 6):

One parameter of the opamp you are violating is the input common-mode range.

For the LM358 and many other opamps the inputs must not be with a certain voltage of the positive or negative supply rail.

The LM358 was one of the first that allowed the inputs to go down to the negative rail and is often referred to as a single supply opamp.  Even the LM358 does not allow the inputs to get closer to the positive supply rail than 1.5V, i.e. 3.5V if you are operating off 5V. If you supply the amplifier with not less than 6.5V it would function.  The output would then be 0.2V.

Some opamps have what are called rail-to-rail inputs and do allow the inputs to go to the positive rail.

Another way if you are constrained to a 5V supply is to supply the non-inverting input with a voltage such as 2.5V.  That will allow the opamp to function but with a 48uA input current and 100k feedback the output will attempt to go to -2.3V which is outside the output stage capability since you are only supply it with 0 and 5V.  You could give it a negative supply (say -5V) or reduce the 100k resistor to 50k for example.  The output voltage would then be 2.5V (the input common mode) - 48uA*50K (the voltage developed across the feedback resistor 2.4v) = 0.1V at the output.

The series resistor to the non-inverting input serves no function as the current into the opamp is so small (~25nA) that it will not change the voltage.  If you connect the 100k variable as a potentiometer between 5V and ground it would allow you to adjust the input voltage.

[image]

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, due to the listed spec sheet snippet provided unless I am providing a +V rail source that is at minimum 1.5V greater than the input to either the inverting or non-inverting leads it will not function. I do understand the voltage range concept though. Even if I gave 3kV to the +V rail (Which would melt the thing but just for arguments sake) and grounded -V rail and decided to put a +5V source into an inverting configuration with a gain of 1. I would still not see it work because it would output -5V which is below the minimum of 0 from the Grounded -V.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, currently trying to test the circuit and decided to put the 5V into the +V rail and provide 3.3V to the non-inverting lead but in simulation I'm still being left with a negative mv output which obviously can't work so I'm just playing around with it just for the sake of getting some sort of output.

Comment: Try reducing the feedback resistor - in the example I did with  2.5V on the non-inv input the resistor needed to be 50k or less.

Comment: I changed it to a 10k resistor, because I thought the same thing as well and thought the - node was making it larger than the 3.5V max for the input. No dice.

Comment: What voltage do you get with the 48uA input and with no input?

Comment: Ok so when I set the + node to GND then there is no output at all. Which makes sense since it's an inverting configuration if I have no + bias then the op amp will output the negative value of the difference between the two which exceeds the 0 to +5V range. So I decided to test it by taking the current supply and attaching it as the input to the + node and just attach the resistor I had going into the + before and tie it to ground. So now it is a non-inverting configuration and now it works. Currently trying to test exact voltage values now.

Comment: Set the +input to the 3.3V or similar.  Leave the feedback resistor in place but don't connect anything else to the inverting input.  The output should go the same voltage as the  +input.

Comment: When opto-isolater isn't blocked (35uA) = 3.36V measured. When isolater is blocked (3-5uA) = 1.52V measured. This is with the 10k resistor, let me see if the old 100k causes any sort of saturation problems. I assume it will since 3.36V is already getting close to the op-amp max output of 5V - 1.5. Edit: Tried the 100k and the op amp will not output any more which is likely due to it just completely exceeding the limit set by the rail. I'll need a larger voltage supply before I can get it working.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ivok8Sh.png This is my current set up that I got working, I didn't correct the rails but as you see I basically changed it to a non-inverting configuration and it works right now. Also thanks a TON for your help, really cleared up some serious misconceptions on my part. I think if I want to have my old circuit configuration where I have a voltage source as a bias and the current leading into the - node I'll need a much higher rail voltage.

Comment: That schematic is not correct - you can't have a current generator going into non-inverting input! What is the implementation of the current generator anyway?

Comment: You're right: http://i.imgur.com/BoH4qIQ.jpg is my current circuit implementation. I added a 10k resistor in series to convert it into a voltage. The bottom right 'final product' is where I want to take the design but it looks like in order to do it I will need a voltage supply that's not just from the arduino.

Comment: The simplest way is to connect the 10k resistor in the emitter lead of your photo-coupler output to ground.  Put the junction of the 10k and emitter to the +input of the opamp.  That will give you a voltage that is zero with no light getting progressively higher as the light increases.

Comment: Well thanks for all your help. I've done that. I have noticed that resistor value connecting the inverting input and the output doesn't seem to change the voltage across the meter. 10k remains the best choice but I've noticed it becomes much less responsive at 20k and at 500 ohms. Anything more than ~50k and I believe the gain is so large the op amp input voltage is exceeding the rail so it won't work. Am I just limited because I have a 3.3V and 5V supply or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem with your schematic is that you have the power to the opamp hooked up backwards.  The positive supply input needs to be more positive than the negative supply input.  Put another way, you are trying to power the opamp from -5 V, which won't work.

Comment: The top schematic is ambiguous but the lower one showing the pinout is correct.

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about the circuitlab schematic or the hand drawn one? If circuitlab I may have just switched the two by accident but on my circuit I do have a +5V into the +ve rail and the -ve attached to ground since this is a single rail op-amp.

Comment: @kevin: The schematic is not ambiguous.  It clearly shows the power connected backwards.  Since there is only one schematic, "top" and "lower" make no sense.  The other figure is a wiring diagram, and poorly photographed at that, so ignoring it.  Besides, expecting us to know the pinout, without even a link to the datasheet, is unrealistic.

Comment: I apologize, I'm unable to attach more than two links to the main thread: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf.

Comment: It depends on the symbol.  I have used schematic editors where the only way to get the inverting input at the top is to turn the symbol upside down putting the positive power input at the bottom. I agree it is confusing and I never did it but other engineers did (and I complained about it!).  The symbol should have a polarity indication or pin number.  The lower diagram is correct though. I agree that a data sheet link should have been included butt the LM358 uses the standard dual opamp in an 8 pin package pinout so I do know it.